# MatLab error:Exceeded the maximum number (8) of light sources

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to make a movie by plotting isosurf of a my data at each time step. However, I get the following error and the code runs very slow. The error is:

```
[Warning: Error updating Light.
 Exceeded the maximum number (8) of light sources
```

The line that the error refers to is the following:

```
drawnow;
```

I searched on how to solve this problem but did not found any solution. The same problem has been reported in the following link:
[https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/471429-exceeded-the-maximum-number-8-of-[light-sources-when-trying-to-plot-two-shrinking-spheres-on-the][1]](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/471429-exceeded-the-maximum-number-8-of-%5Blight-sources-when-trying-to-plot-two-shrinking-spheres-on-the%5D%5B1%5D)

Could some one please help me with removing this error?

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. How could we possibly tell you how to fix your code if we can’t see your code???

Comment: There is an example in the link. @CrisLuengo

Comment: Questions have to be self-contained, not depend on external links that could break. Also, that’s not your code, fixing it might not help you.